# ¿Cómo validar un input type="radio" con atributos name diferentes?

Tags: laravel-5, validación, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

Estoy tratando de validar los datos de una encuesta, dónde cada par de input type="radio" tienen un nombre diferente dependiendo del id así: `name="option{{ $pregunta->id }}"`. Mi problema es que las funciones para validar no aceptan variables, mi solución fue validar todo el request en el controlador, pero creo que no tengo la sintaxis correcta, aquí les dejo el código del blade y del controlador:

```
<form id="poll" class="card-deck" method="POST" action="{{ route('respuestas', $encuesta->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        @foreach($encuesta->preguntas as $pregunta)
                <p class="card-text">{{ $pregunta->pregunta }}</p>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="option{{ $pregunta->id }}" id="pregunta" autocomplete="off" value="1"> Sí
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="option{{ $pregunta->id }}" id="pregunta" autocomplete="off" value="0"> No
                    </label>
                </div>
        @endforeach
        <a href="#" role="button"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Enviar</button></a>
</form>
```

En mi controlador intenté:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(\Request::all(), ['required'], ['Todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas para poder enviar el sondeo.']);
$validator->validate();
//Code to save the request
```

Si tienen otra alternativa para darle solución a guardar las preguntas de una encuesta, les agradezco me la expliquen.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente hay muchas formas de hacerlo, sin embargo para seguir las convenciones de Laravel, la mejor idea puede ser validar todo en el Request.

Teniendo en cuenta que dices tener nombres dinámicos para los distintos valores que serán incluidos en el Request, la mejor idea puede ser agrupar las preguntas en arreglos:

```
<input type="radio" name="option[{{ $pregunta->id }}]" id="pregunta" autocomplete="off" value="1">
```

De esa forma tendras un arreglo en PHP al momento de recibir la información en el request y con esto puedes generar tu arreglo de reglas de validación:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'option.*' => 'required',  // las validaciones que necesites
    ];
}
```

Si necesitas validaciones más complejas, recuerda que ya tienes el objeto Request y que puedes usar un foreach o cualquier otra función de iteración, lo importante es generar un array como salida en el método rules().

Comment: Tienes razón, había visto varias respuestas que le daban solución con un _array_ pero no sabía como convertir mis respuestas en un _array_ en primer lugar, voy a intentarlo así.

Comment: Quedo pendiente del resultado.